# Redirect after user pass form submit

Tags: 8

I'm trying to do a redirect after hitting the submit button in a Drupal 8 reset password form.

I use the `theme_form_alter` hook and a function as a new submit actions. The problem is, that the redirect works but no email is send. 
If I uncomment the line for the new submit hook the mail is send but of course there is no redirect.

```
function theme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form['#form_id'] == 'user_pass') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'user_pass_redirect';
  }
}

function user_pass_redirect(&$form, $form_state) {
  $url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', [
    'node' => '87',
  ]);

 $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
}
```

I'm doing exactly the same thing for the `contact_message_personal_form` form and it works.

So, I have no idea why that happens for the `contact_message_personal_form` and the `user_pass` has isn't working.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I compared the output from a dump of user_pass $form and contact_message_personal_form $form variable.
 
My problem was, that my `$form['actions']['submit']['#submit']` array was empty. So I added the missing '`::submitForm`' parameter 
and everything works.

```
function module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form['#form_id'] == 'user_pass') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '::submitForm';
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'user_pass_redirect'; 
  }
}

function user_pass_redirect(&$form, $form_state) {
  $url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', [
    'node' => '87',
  ]);
  $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
}
```

I have no idea why my variable was empty but this works for me.